# Retrieving variable from another class

Tags: python-3.x, class, tkinter

I am programming a GUI using Tkinter. In one of the classes I have defined a variable (entry_filename) and would like to use it in another class. A part of the code is as follows:

```
class Loginpage(tk.Frame,Search):


    def __init__(self,parent,controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self,parent)
        self.controller=controller
        self.label_user=tk.Label(self, text="Username")
        self.label_user.grid(row=0, column=0)
        self.label_pass=tk.Label(self, text="Password")
        self.label_pass.grid(row=1, column=0)

        self.entry_user=tk.Entry(self)
        self.entry_user.focus_set()
        self.entry_user.grid(row=0, column=1)

        self.entry_pass=tk.Entry(self,show="*")
        self.entry_pass.grid(row=1, column=1)


        self.button=ttk.Button(self, text="Login",command= self.Logincheck)
        self.button.grid(columnspan=2)

    def Logincheck(self):
        global username
        global password
        try:
            username=self.entry_user.get()
            password=self.entry_pass.get()

            self.ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
            self.ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())

            self.ssh.connect(server, username=username, password=password)#input your username&password
            button1 = ttk.Button(self, text="Click to Continue",command= lambda: self.controller.show_frame(Inputpage))
            button1.grid(columnspan=2)
        except:
            tm.showerror("Login error", "Incorrect username/password")


class Inputpage(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.controller=controller

        self.filein_label=tk.Label(self,text="Input file name")
        self.filein_label.grid(row=0,column=0)

        self.entry_filename=tk.Entry(self)
        self.entry_filename.focus_set()
        self.entry_filename.grid(row=0,column=1)

        self.button1 = ttk.Button(self, text="Click to Continue",command= lambda: self.controller.show_frame(Graphpage))
        self.button1.grid(columnspan=2)


class Graphpage(tk.Frame,Inputpage):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.controller=controller
        self.label = tk.Label(self, text="Graph Page!", font=LARGE_FONT)
        self.label.pack(pady=10,padx=10)

        button1 = ttk.Button(self, text="Back to Input Page",command=lambda: self.controller.show_frame(Inputpage))
        button1.pack()

        filename=Inputpage.entry_filename.get()
```

The Graphpage calls the variable filename which is later used to create the graph (that part of the code is omitted here). When the code is run the following error is returned:
TypeError: Cannot create a consistent method resolution
order (MRO) for bases Frame, Inputpage

It seems that I have hit another roadblock in attempting to solve the earlier issue, however, if I can understand the resolution to this, I hope that I can attempt to solve further issues. Thanks for your help

Comment: Do you want those page classes to be different Frames in a window or to be different windows? Apart from this sorry if my answer is so simple that led you in a wrong path. I was thinking in configuration data united under a class just for acessing through the name of the class. Not tkinter widgets you are creating somewhere. You can define a global var like `input_filename = tk.StringVar()` and associate it via `textvariable=input_filename` when you create the text widget. Then `input_filename.get()` will work in other places (these vars share a Tk() namespace (the main window tkinter window)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The culprit is that you should not share
class member variables that way.

If different classes share some common
data, that data is probably another class
and they can inherit from it.

```
class CommonData():
    client = 100


class A(CommonData):
    def __init__(self):
        print(A.client)

class B(CommonData):
    def __init__(self):
        print(B.client)

a = A()
b = B()

CommonData.client = 300

print(a.client)
print(b.client)
```

In above case every instance of A and every instance of B
share all the CommonData class variables, like client.

```
CommonData.client = 400

class C():
    pass
```

You can use multiple inheritance too.
define all common data as CommonData attributes
and use CommonData as a class to hold data, like
in above example, don't create instances from it:

```
class D(C, CommonData):
    def __init__(self):
        print(D.client)

c = C()
d = D()
```

A simpler option would be to just define
a variable CommonData in the outer scope and 
use it from anywhere:

```
common_data = 500

class A():
    def __init__(self):
        global common_data
        print(common_data)
        common_data = 200
        # ...
```

But global variables are generally seen as a bad thing  in a program as their use can become a problem for several reasons.

Yet another way is to pass the variable to the object initializer.
That makes the instance to keep its own value copied from
the creation value:

```
common_data = 600

class A():
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.common = data
        print(self.common)

a = A(common_data)
common_data = 0
print(a.common)
```

If you run all the code above it will print

```
100
100
300
300
400
600
600
```

## Edit:

See my comment to your answer and a simple example here.
Here I opt for two global references to tkinter StringVars.
The stringvars exist themselves in the Tk() namespace, like the
widgets; besides they are global Python names.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk



class Page1(tk.Toplevel):
    def __init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(parent, *args, **kwargs)
        self.title('Page1')
        self.label1 = ttk.Label(self, text='Filename:')
        self.entry1 = ttk.Entry(self, textvariable=input_file1)
        self.label1.pack(side=tk.LEFT)
        self.entry1.pack()


class Page2(tk.Toplevel):
    def __init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(parent, *args, **kwargs)
        self.title('Page2')
        self.label1 = ttk.Label(self, text='Filename:')
        self.entry1 = ttk.Entry(self, textvariable=input_file2)
        self.button1 = ttk.Button(self, text='Copy Here', command=copy_filename)
        self.label1.pack(side=tk.LEFT)
        self.entry1.pack(side=tk.LEFT)
        self.button1.pack()

def copy_filename():
    input_file2.set(input_file1.get())

root = tk.Tk() # has to exist for the StringVars to be created
root.iconify()
input_file1 = tk.StringVar()
input_file2 = tk.StringVar()

page1 = Page1(root)
page2 = Page2(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Now in the next example see how I turn the stringvars into variables
of Page1 and Page2 instances (not classes), making them local instead
of global. Then I am forced to pass a reference for the widget page1
object into the widget page2 object.

This looks more close to what you are asking.

About MRO trouble, if you avoid multiple inheritance
it won't happen.

Or you deal with it usually by using  `super()`

In your case the error is because you store the widget in
the object/instance (in `self.somename`), and then you try
to invoke a widget method qualifying with the class name.
There is no widget there in the class for you to use a method.

So the search using the method resolution order fails, 
because there is no corresponding name there.

Note that I have not used multiple inheritance, so I could 
have just written `tk.Frame.` instead of calling `super`. I like
super because it makes clear in the text that I am invoking the parent
class but super is really needed only when there are multiple parents
and various levels of subclassing (usually forming a diamond shape).

Now the example:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk


class Page1(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(parent, *args, **kwargs)

        self.input_file1 = tk.StringVar()

        self.label1 = ttk.Label(self, text='Filename:')
        self.entry1 = ttk.Entry(self, textvariable=self.input_file1)
        self.label1.pack(side=tk.LEFT)
        self.entry1.pack()


class Page2(tk.Frame):
    # note the page1 reference being
    # passed to initializer and stored in a var
    # local to this instance:
    def __init__(self, parent, page1, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(parent, *args, **kwargs)

        self.page1 = page1

        self.input_file2 = tk.StringVar()

        self.label1 = ttk.Label(self, text='Filename:')
        self.entry1 = ttk.Entry(self, textvariable=self.input_file2)
        self.button1 = ttk.Button(self, text='Copy Here',
            command=self.copy_filename)
        self.label1.pack(side=tk.LEFT)
        self.entry1.pack(side=tk.LEFT)
        self.button1.pack()

    def copy_filename(self):
        # see how the page1 refernce is used to acess
        # the Page1 instance
        self.input_file2.set(page1.input_file1.get())

root = tk.Tk() # has to exist for the StringVars to be created

page1 = Page1(root)
page2 = Page2(root, page1) # pass a reference to page1 instance
page1.pack(side=tk.LEFT)
page2.pack(side=tk.LEFT)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: I run into this error: TypeError: Cannot create a consistent method resolution
order (MRO) for bases Frame, Inputpage.. Please see the edited code

Comment: @SchlatorBorgenson see my edit with two new examples.

Answer (score 1):

`ssh` is a local variable inside function `LoginCheck` so you are not able to retrieve it from another class. One thing possible to do is to define `ssh` as `self.ssh` so it will be accessible through `instance_of_Loginpage.ssh`. It will work only when you will pass an instance of `Loginpage` into an instance of `Graphpage`. If you need access to an ssh connection from many places I suggest to create another class just to handle ssh (you can use Borg patter to achieve it).

Comment: I am new to the concept of classes, could you expand on "instance_of_Loginpage.ssh". Thank you

Comment: The dict of Loginpage only has the method Logincheck in it, so I am confused on how to access ssh

Comment: @SchlatorBorgenson, maQ's answer is ok. He means that when you assign to `self.ssh` you are assigning to an instance attribute, not a class attribute. Class atributes are shared by all instances. Instance attributes belong to the instance only (and can hide class attributes of the same name). An instance (that is a class object)  is created any time you call a class like in page = LoginPage()

Comment: I wouldn't recommend using patterns right now, before OP understands more basic things with Python classes. Later, yes, of course.

Comment: @progmatico: I have done a small modification to the code to make it more easily understandable to myself. I have added a new page called input page. In the Inputpage a filename is given, and this is passed as input to the Graphpage. However, an error is returned as seen in the edited question.

Comment: I commented the OP question and edited my answer with two additional examples